# htaccess: I can't redirect to nested subfolders correctly on the WordPress app

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, wordpress

I have a multilingual WordPress site that has two languages: en and tr, **It's site A**.

I wanna put my other WordPress site inside /tr/shop/ folder, **It's site B**.

Just need only these rules:

- **/en/anything/** goes to site A (also /en/)
- **/tr/anything/** goes to site A (also /tr/)
- **/tr/shop/** goes to site B inside the /tr/shop subfolder.

Currently:

- If visitors go to /en/ or /en/anything, It's OK.
- If visitors go to /tr/shop/, they see site B, It's OK. Because the folder exists.
- Visitors who go to /tr/* see a 404 error. Because /tr/ is a physical folder but empty. It's just a language prefix, not a physical folder. I need to exclude /tr/ folder from requests.

How can I do it?

My current .htaccess is below but not working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /

# Exclude /tr/ from rewriting
RewriteRule ^tr(/.*)?$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# Beginning of shop part
RewriteRule ^tr/shop(/.*)?$ /tr/shop/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tr(/.*)?$ /index.php [L]
# End of shop part
</IfModule>
```

Comment: [Cross-site post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76687238/htaccess-i-cant-redirect-to-nested-subfolders-correctly-on-the-wordpress-app) where this question already has an answer.

Comment: It's also solved on [Cross-site post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76687238/htaccess-i-cant-redirect-to-nested-subfolders-correctly-on-the-wordpress-app?noredirect=1#76689144) ❤️ thanks MrWhite!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it already has an answer on another site.